# Ubuntu with Openbox: desktop switching not working

Tags: lubuntu, workspaces, openbox

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. It came with Unity and then I installed `lubuntu-desktop`. I am now using Openbox that comes with Lubuntu. From its documentation, Ctrl+Alt+arrow keys should switch desktop but it does not work. Nothing happens when I press Ctrl+Alt+up/left/right. When I press Ctrl+Alt+down, the icon of desktop switching shows up but still it does not switch. However, super+F1/F2/F3/F4 works. I don't understand what is wrong here. Could anyone point a possible direction for me? I really appreciate it!

Comment: go into your settings and make sure you have more than one desktop. You may have to change the value from 1 to more than 1, like 4 for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that it had nothing to do with the system itself. It was a problem caused by VMWare hotkey. By default VMWare uses Ctrl+Alt as hot key, which conflicts with Ctrl+Alt+arrow in Openbox. After changing hot key preference in VMWare, it works perfectly.

Comment: Probably it would have been solved much faster if you mentioned that your lubuntu is a virtual machine in vmware. Remember to include that in the future into your questions.  Otherwise,  welcome to the site and congrats on solving the issue